# Relación uno a muchos con Laravel y GraphQL

Tags: laravel, graphql

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación con Laravel y GraphQL y estoy teniendo un problema, el escenario es sencillo, tengo una tabla PERSONAS (ID, NOMBRE, APELLIDO, GENERO) la cual tiene un campo GENERO el cual almacena el ID de la tabla GENEROS (ID, NOMBRE). No se que estoy haciendo mal que me trae el genero en null.
Les dejo el código ojala puedan ayudarme.
Muchas gracias !!!

Modelo Persona:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Persona extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'PERSONAS'; 
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

    public function genero()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Genero::class, 'ID');
    }
}
```

Modelo Genero:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Genero extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'GENEROS'; 
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

    public function personas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Persona::class, 'GENERO');
    }
}
```

Tipo Persona:

```
namespace App\GraphQL\Type;

use GraphQL;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Folklore\GraphQL\Support\Type as GraphQLType;

class PersonaType extends GraphQLType
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Persona'
    ];

    public function fields()
    {
        return [
            'ID' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::int())
            ],
            'NOMBRE' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string())
            ],
            'APELLIDO' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string())
            ],
            'GENERO' => [
                'type' => GraphQL::type('Genero')
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Tipo Genero:

```
namespace App\GraphQL\Type;

use GraphQL;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Folklore\GraphQL\Support\Type as GraphQLType;

class GeneroType extends GraphQLType
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Genero'
    ];

    public function fields()
    {
        return [
            'ID' => [
                'type' => Type::int()
            ],
            'NOMBRE' => [
                'type' => Type::string()
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Query GraphQL:

```
namespace App\GraphQL\Query;

use GraphQL;
use App\Persona;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Folklore\GraphQL\Support\Query;
use Folklore\GraphQL\Support\SelectFields;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;

class AllPersonsQuery extends Query
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'allPersons'
    ];

    public function type()
    {
        return Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('Persona'));
    }

    public function resolve($root, $args, $context, ResolveInfo $info)
    {
        $fields = $info->getFieldSelection();
        $persons = Persona::query();

        foreach ($fields as $field => $keys) {
            if ($field === 'GENERO') {
                $persons->with('genero');
            }
        }

        return $persons->get();
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "query": "{allPersons{ID, NOMBRE, APELLIDO, GENERO{ID, NOMBRE}}}"
}
```

Resultado:

```
{
    "data": {
        "allPersons": [
            {
                "ID": 1,
                "NOMBRE": "Romina                                                                          ",
                "APELLIDO": "Capurro                                                                         ",
                "GENERO": {
                    "ID": null,
                    "NOMBRE": null
                }
            },
            {
                "ID": 2,
                "NOMBRE": "Andres                                                                          ",
                "APELLIDO": "Hernandez                                                                       ",
                "GENERO": {
                    "ID": null,
                    "NOMBRE": null
                }
            },
            {
                "ID": 3,
                "NOMBRE": "Salvador                                                                        ",
                "APELLIDO": "Hernandez Capurro                                                               ",
                "GENERO": {
                    "ID": null,
                    "NOMBRE": null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: intenta con `return $persons->latest()->get();`

Comment: Esto solamente ordena los resultados pero sigo obteniendo los géneros en null, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Veo algunos fallos en cuanto a nomenclatura. El modelo es un elemento individual, generalmente se les llama de forma singular.

En las relaciones, tienes que definir, el modelo al que pertenece, y en caso de que no uses la nomenclatura que asume Laravel (En este caso seria 'generos_id'), tendrás que decirles el campo que relaciona a ambos modelos, en tu caso es 'GENERO'.

El nombre del método del belongsTo, esta bien, ya que el modelo solo tiene un genero.
Pero el genero tiene varias personas, por tanto conviene que llames a el método en plural

```
public function genero()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Generos', 'GENERO');
}

public function personas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Personas', 'GENERO');
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Francisco, hice los cambios que me sugerís pero sigo obteniendo el genero en null. Te dejo el código de la query quizás ayude en algo.